# Huge problem to parse this "simple" html page

Tags: html, rebol

I'm trying to parse http://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXDJX:.DJI and I can't achieve it I can't see why:

```
symbol_list: ["GOOG" "AAPL" "MSFT" "INDEXDJX:.DJI"]
foreach symbol symbol_list [
  url0: rejoin [http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q= symbol]
  ;stock-data: read/lines url
  dir: make-dir/deep to-rebol-file "askpoweruser/stock-download/google/"
  either none? filename: find symbol ":" [filename: symbol
  url: rejoin [url0 "&output=csv"]
    content: read url
    out-string: copy rejoin ["Time;Open;High;Low;Close;Volume" newline]
    reversed-quotes: reverse parse/all content ",^/"

    foreach [v c l h o d] reversed-quotes [
        either not (error? try [d: to-date d]) [
            d: rejoin [d/year "-" d/month "-" d/day]
            append out-string rejoin [d ";" o ";" h ";" l ";" c ";" v newline]
        ][

        ]

    ]
    write to-rebol-file rejoin [dir symbol ".csv"] out-string
  ][
    filename: next next filename
    out: copy []
    for i 0 1 1 [
    p: i
    url: rejoin [url0 "&start=" (p * 200) "&num=" ((p + 1) * 200)]
    content: read url
    rule: [to "<table" thru "<table" to ">" thru ">"
    to "<table" thru "<table" to ">" thru ">"
    to "<table" thru "<table" to ">" thru ">"
    copy quotes to </table> to end
    ]
    parse content rule

parse load/markup quotes [
    some [set tag tag! (probe tag) | set x string! (
        if (not none? tag) [
        if ((left-range tag 3) = "<td") [
            replace/all (replace/all x "^/" "") "," ""
            append out x
        ]
        ]
    )
    ]
]
    ;write/lines to-rebol-file rejoin [dir filename "_" p ".html"] quotes

    ]
    write to-rebol-file rejoin [dir filename "_temp" ".txt"] mold out
    remove/part out 2
    out-string: copy rejoin ["Time;Open;High;Low;Close;Volume" newline]
    out: reverse out
    insert/only out "" 1

    foreach [x v c l h o d] out [

        either not (error? try [d: to-date d]) [
            d: rejoin [d/year "-" d/month "-" d/day]
            append out-string rejoin [d ";" o ";" h ";" l ";" c ";" v newline]
        ][
            probe d
            input
        ]
    ]
write/lines to-rebol-file rejoin [dir filename ".csv"] out-string
  ]

]
```

Finally I do it another way (see my own answer below) using parse instead of load/markup which appears to be simpler at first but google html doesn't seem to be very kind so I changed my mind :

```
parse quotes [
    some [to "<td" thru "<td" to ">" thru ">" [copy x to "<" | copy x to end] (append out replace/all x "^/" "")]
    to end
]
```

sample output:

```
Time;Open;High;Low;Close;Volume
2009-11-30;10,309.77;10,364.34;10,263.29;10,344.84;223,576,049
2009-12-1;10,343.82;10,501.28;10,343.44;10,471.58;190,219,357
2009-12-2;10,470.44;10,513.52;10,421.47;10,452.68;159,501,469
2009-12-3;10,455.63;10,507.63;10,350.05;10,366.15;243,970,136
2009-12-4;10,368.57;10,516.70;10,311.81;10,388.90;460,658,589
2009-12-7;10,386.86;10,443.16;10,360.18;10,390.11;196,577,978
2009-12-8;10,385.42;10,385.65;10,249.84;10,285.97;221,774,698
2009-12-9;10,282.85;10,342.27;10,235.63;10,337.05;188,605,901
2009-12-10;10,336.00;10,444.60;10,335.77;10,405.83;195,906,049
2009-12-11;10,403.41;10,484.05;10,400.08;10,471.50;179,968,842
2009-12-14;10,471.28;10,514.66;10,471.28;10,501.05;154,359,615
```

Comment: Why use [to "<table" thru "<table"] ?  This is the same as [thru "<table"]

Comment: I don't remember why but in some cases it doesn't behave the same will try to remember it some day if I can :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I gave up using load/markup and directly use parse, now it works:

```
symbol_list: ["GOOG" "AAPL" "MSFT" "INDEXDJX:.DJI"]
foreach symbol symbol_list [
  url0: rejoin [http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q= symbol]
  ;stock-data: read/lines url
  dir: make-dir/deep to-rebol-file "askpoweruser/stock-download/google/"
  either none? filename: find symbol ":" [filename: symbol
  url: rejoin [url0 "&output=csv"]
    content: read url
    out-string: copy rejoin ["Time;Open;High;Low;Close;Volume" newline]
    reversed-quotes: reverse parse/all content ",^/"

    foreach [v c l h o d] reversed-quotes [
        either not (error? try [d: to-date d]) [
            d: rejoin [d/year "-" d/month "-" d/day]
            append out-string rejoin [d ";" o ";" h ";" l ";" c ";" v newline]
        ][

        ]

    ]
    write to-rebol-file rejoin [dir symbol ".csv"] out-string
  ][
    filename: next next filename
    out: copy []
    for i 0 1 1 [
    p: i
    url: rejoin [url0 "&start=" (p * 200) "&num=" ((p + 1) * 200)]
    content: read url
    rule: [to "<table" thru "<table" to ">" thru ">"
    to "<table" thru "<table" to ">" thru ">"
    to "<table" thru "<table" to ">" thru ">"
    copy quotes to </table> to end
    ]
    parse content rule

parse quotes [
    some [to "<td" thru "<td" to ">" thru ">" [copy x to "<" | copy x to end] (append out replace/all x "^/" "")]
    to end
]
    ;write/lines to-rebol-file rejoin [dir filename "_" p ".html"] quotes

    ]
    write to-rebol-file rejoin [dir filename "_temp" ".txt"] mold out
    ;remove/part out 2
    out-string: copy rejoin ["Time;Open;High;Low;Close;Volume" newline]
    out: reverse out    

    foreach [v c l h o d] out [
       d: parse/all d " ,"
       d: to-date rejoin [d/4 "-" d/1 "-" d/2]
       d: rejoin [d/year "-" d/month "-" d/day]
       append out-string rejoin [d ";" o ";" h ";" l ";" c ";" v newline]
    ]
    write to-rebol-file rejoin [dir filename ".csv"] out-string
  ]

]
```